# Find the special character from an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string

I am trying to write one validation in a user input box where alpha numeric value is allowed along with some special character. I trying to show one error message if a user entered special char which is not supported in my application.

```
   var inputKey = "abcdfg34$@!"
```

So at first place am doing one filter to get special char out of this string

```
   var inp = inputKey.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''); // Now ip = @!
```

$scope.specialchar contains list of allowed spl char

```
   $scope.specialchar = [@,#,$,%,<,^,<];

   for(var i in $rootScope.specialChar ){

              if(( inp.indexOf($scope.specialChar[i].value) > -1 ))
                  {
                  $scope.charAllowedText = true;
                  count++;
                  }

          }
         if(count == 0) - display error messagae
```

So above code is working fine if occurance of first spl char is the one which is not listed . Above example show (!) is not listed But since my string contains @! the condition (count ==0) is failing. Again i want to print what special character has user entered on error prompt.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you can do it use regex replace allowed special chars with '' like the code above only?

Comment: why cant you test with regex and then if the test fails, show the error message!

Comment: and your checking is wrong,must be total of the special chars.`   if(count != inp.length) - display error messagae`

Comment: *above code is working fine* really? with this? `$scope.specialchar = [@,#,$,%,<,^,<];` - you should be getting something like `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: @user2282534 use custom directives instead of this .. its ugly and not the best practice cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Regex way to filter the disallowed chars

```js
var allowed=['-','@'];
var regex=new RegExp('[a-z0-9'+allowed.join('')+']','ig');

var tests=[
  "holi-java",
  "@name",
  "@-#$@"
];


tests.forEach(function(test){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(test)+" disallowed chars were:"+JSON.stringify(test.replace(regex,'')));
});
```

### Javascript way to filter the disallowed chars

```js
    var allowed=['-','@'];
    

    var tests=[
      "holi-java",
      "@name",
      "@-#$@"
    ];
    function disallowed(input){
       var rest=input.replace(/[a-z0-9]/g,'');
       var disallowed=[]; 
       for(var i in rest){
         if(allowed.indexOf(rest[i])==-1)
          disallowed.push(rest[i]);
       }
       return disallowed;
    }

    tests.forEach(function(test){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(test)+" disallowed chars were:"+JSON.stringify(disallowed(test)));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when setting `$scope.specialChar`, each character in the array should be wrapped in quotes so that it is read as a string:

```
$scope.specialchar = ['@', '#', '$', '%', '<', '^', '<'];
```

Secondly, when checking if the input contains one of the special characters, you should just use `$scope.specialChar[i]` (without `.value`, being that you are trying to access just an element in an array, not the `value` property of that element).

```
inp.indexOf($scope.specialChar[i]) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this directive instead of above code ..

```
angular.module('test')
  .directive('validChar', function() {
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        if(!ngModelCtrl) {
          return;
        }

        ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) {
          if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
            val = '';
          }
          var clean = val.replace( /[a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
          if (val !== clean) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return clean;
        });

        element.bind('keypress', function(event) {
          if(event.keyCode === 32) {
            event.preventDefault();
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```